# Get saved data from MongoDB collection and use it in code on button click [Node JS express]

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, ejs

I have an code in NodeJS which stores data in collection specific to the user.

This the router to GET and POST the data from EJS form.

```
server.get('/changeaccounts', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const accounts = await account.find({user: req.user.id}).lean()
        res.render("backend/changeaccounts", {
            name: req.user.name,
            accounts
        });
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
   
})

server.post('/changeaccounts', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        req.body.user = req.user.id
        await account.create(req.body)
        res.redirect('/dashboard')
    }catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
})
```

This sends the data entered from the form to the collection specific to every logged in user(included in the attached image)
[Here is the image for database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpfUE.png)

I have an `forEach` loop going in the EJS template

```
 <% if (accounts) {%>
              <table class = "striped">
                   <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Account</th>
                        <th>Select Account</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <% accounts.forEach(accounts => { %>
                        <tr>
                      <td><a href="<% accounts._id %>"></a><%= accounts.title%></td>
                      <td><button type="submit" id="buttonforaccount" class = "btn btn-primary col-auto" >Use this account</button></td>
                        </tr>
                      <%});%>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                <%} else {%>
                  <p>You have no accounts added</p>
                <% } %>
```

***The output is given in the second attached image.***
[This is the image for the table output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBpa6.png)

What I want to do is when the Button is clicked by the user, it fetches the `title and password` (as shown in first image) from the collection and is usable through my code as follows.

```
control.post('/like', (req, res, next) => {
    let tags = req.body.likes;
    let title = From the collection on button click //title here
    let password = from the collection on button click //password here
    iglike(title, password, tags);
    next();
    res.send(title);
    res.send(password);
    res.send(tags);
});
```

Comment: where are you using /changeaccounts post route in your frontend?

Comment: In my dashboard/changeaccounts